# Rock, paper, scissors in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, boolean

I'm having some difficulty finishing up my code for a RPS game. The instructions are as follows:
c.  Main button-click code.
i.  You need to prompt the user for one of the three letters using an input box as we’ve done before.
ii. Get the random letter from your custom method.
iii.    Pass both the user’s letter and random computer letter to your other method.
iv. If it returned true, tell the user they won in the label you added to the form, otherwise tell them they lost in that label.

I think i did 1 and 2 correctly but I'm having problems with 3 and 4. can somebody help!!

This is my code so far

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim randomObject As New Random()

    Private Property user As String

    Private Property computer As Random

    Function GetRandomRPSLetter() As String
        randomObject.Next(1, 4)
        Dim computer As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 4)
        If computer = 1 Then
            Return "r"
        ElseIf computer = 2 Then
            Return "p"
        Else
            Return "s"
        End If

    End Function
    Function GetRPSRoundWinner(ByVal user As String, ByVal computer As String) As String
        If user = "r" Then
            If computer = "r" Then
                Return False
            ElseIf computer = "p" Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        ElseIf user = "p" Then
            If computer = "r" Then
                Return True
            ElseIf computer = "p" Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            If computer = "r" Then
                Return False
            ElseIf computer = "p" Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                                    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        user = InputBox("Please input r, p, or s to play")

        GetRandomRPSLetter()



    End Sub
    Sub GetRPSRoundWinner()
        If GetRPSRoundWinner(True) Then Return
        Label1.Text = "You win"

    End Sub

    Private Function GetRPSRoundWinner(p1 As Boolean) As Boolean
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function

End Class
```

Now i called GetRPSRoundWinner

```
Private Sub Button1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                                ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    user = InputBox("Please input r, p, or s to play")

    GetRandomRPSLetter()

    GetRPSRoundWinner()



End Sub
```

Can anyone help me in how to compare them?

Thanks very much to all!

Comment: I would recommend using an `Enum` for the values `Rock`, `Paper`, `Scissors`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm so lost. Steven told me my mistakes, but I don't know how to fix them!

Answer (score 1):

- Your `GetRPSRoundWinner` method should return a `Boolean` rather than a `String`.  Turning `Option Strict On` will alleviate these kinds of errors.
- You call your `GetRandomRPSLetter` method in the button click event handler, but then you never take the return value from that and use it to compare the user's input with the randomly generated computer move.
- You never call `GetRPSRoundWinner` from anywhere.
- You have three overloads of your `GetRPSRoundWinner` method, but only one of them is actually useful.

Comment: This is my first vb.net class so I'm really lost. I already change GetRPSRoundWinner to a Boolean. Can you help me with the other?

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes and it works for me. I did not test if your functions are getting the right winner, but I think it is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim randomObject As New Random()

    Private Property user As String

    Private Property computer As Random

    Function GetRandomRPSLetter() As String
        randomObject.Next(1, 4)
        Dim computer As Integer = randomObject.Next(1, 4)
        If computer = 1 Then
            Return "r"
        ElseIf computer = 2 Then
            Return "p"
        Else
            Return "s"
        End If

    End Function
    Function ComputeWinner(ByVal user As String, ByVal computer As String) As String
        If user = "r" Then
            If computer = "r" Then
                Return False
            ElseIf computer = "p" Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        ElseIf user = "p" Then
            If computer = "r" Then
                Return True
            ElseIf computer = "p" Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Else
            If computer = "r" Then
                Return False
            ElseIf computer = "p" Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                                    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        user = InputBox("Please input r, p, or s to play")

        Dim ComputerLetter = GetRandomRPSLetter()

        GetRPSRoundWinner(user, ComputerLetter)

    End Sub
    Sub GetRPSRoundWinner(userLetter As String, computerLetter As String)
        If ComputeWinner(userLetter, computerLetter) Then
            Label1.Text = "You win"
        Else
            Label1.Text = "You loose! "
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Do not simply copy and paste the code. Please read it carefully so that you can see the differences.

Comment: Oh my god, I see the difference. I wont copy it. It definitely help me a lot. I wish I knew you guys, so I can buy you guys a beer. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: :D Glad it helped. Please accept this as the answer if it helped you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to show you how to use an `Enum` and take advantage of the implicit conversion to `Integer` it is capable of.

Here are the results of my example code:

[image: desktop]

and the source of the main module with comments:

```
Private rnd As New Random()
''' <summary>
''' Contain values for rock, paper, scissors in a specific
''' numeric order for simplifying with win/loss table
''' </summary>
Public Enum GameHand
    None = -1
    Paper = 0
    Scissors = 1
    Rock = 2
End Enum
''' <summary>
''' Contain values for the result of the game
''' </summary>
Public Enum GameResult
    None = -1
    Loss = 2
    Draw = 0
    Win = 1
End Enum

''' <summary>
''' Compares two RPS hands and returns a win or a loss.
''' If the two hands are the same, or either one is None then the function returns 0
''' </summary>
''' <param name="hand">The human hand (input value)</param>
''' <param name="cpu">The computer hand (output value)</param>
''' <returns>Win, Loss or Draw</returns>
Public Function Play(ByVal hand As GameHand, ByRef cpu As GameHand) As GameResult
    ' Shall we play?
    If hand = GameHand.None Then Return GameResult.None
    ' Pick a random hand
    cpu = rnd.Next(0, 2)
    ' Is it a draw?
    If hand = cpu Then Return GameResult.Draw
    ' win/loss table
    '
    '      P   S   R    
    ' P |      L   W |  
    ' S |  W       L |  
    ' R |  L   W     |  
    '
    ' count how many step away is one hand from the other
    ' in the sequence P S R P S R P S ...
    Dim diff As Integer = (hand + 3 - cpu) Mod 3
    ' two steps is a loss, and one step is a win
    ' Return win or loss
    Return diff
End Function

Sub Main()

    Dim usr As String, win As Integer = 0
    Dim hand As GameHand, cpu As GameHand
    Do
        usr = InputBox("Enter game hand (r/p/s) or quit (q)", "Rock Paper Scissors").ToLower()
        ' Interpret user input 
        Select Case usr
            Case "r"
                hand = GameHand.Rock
            Case "p"
                hand = GameHand.Paper
            Case "s"
                hand = GameHand.Scissors
            Case Else
                hand = GameHand.None
        End Select
        'Play against computer and report back results.
        'Also report computer hand with `ByRef` parameter
        Dim result As GameResult = Play(hand, cpu)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Play {0} against {1} with result {2}", hand, cpu, result))
        'Add wins and subtract losses
        If result = GameResult.Win Then
            win += 1
        ElseIf result = GameResult.Loss Then
            win -= 1
        End If
        ' Check for quit.
    Loop Until usr.Equals("q")
    Console.WriteLine("Player win-loss = " & win)

End Sub
```